# How to convert YAML list to POJO list in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a problem replacing the YAML list to POJO objects. Any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks!

YAML file:

```
- id: "3142"
  engine: "123"
  type: "pressure"
  name: "Engine 123"
  value: 27
  min_value: 0
  max_value: 120
- id: "32234"
  master-sensor-id: "3142"
  type: "temperature"
  value: 82
  min_value: -50
  max_value: 150
```

"type" - contains information about sensor type (allowed values are "pressure" and "temperature")

Comment: what is your pojo structure? Are you using `@ConfiguratioProperties`?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml

Comment: I do not have POJO yet. I have a problem with how to create a POJO that will allow me to store data from a YAML file. The YAML file I will have on the classpath, then convert to POJO, which I will use in REST service later.